# JavaScript TypeError: can't access property "offsetLeft", this is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I've been stuck for a few days. I can't fix my error, I tried adding .bind (this) but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea

errors : TypeError: can't access property "style", this.menu_indicator is undefined
I will have an error on this line
this.menu_indicator.style.left = this.menu_position + "px";

here is my code js , html , css

```js
class TabBar {
    constructor()
    {
        this.menu_bar = document.querySelector('.tab-bottom-bar');
        this.menu_item = document.querySelector('.tab-menu-item');
        this.menu_indicator = document.querySelector('.tab-nav-indicator');
        this.current_item = document.querySelector('.tab-current');
        this.menu_position;
    }

    initMenu()
    {
        this.menu_position = this.current_item.offsetLeft -16;
        this.menu_indicator.style.left = this.menu_position + 'px;
        this.menu_bar.style.backgroundPosition = this.menu_position -8 + 'px';
        let parent = this.menu_item.parentElement;
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(parent.children,
            function(select_menu_item){
                select_menu_item.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    this.menu_position = this.offsetLeft - 16;
                    this.menu_indicator.style.left = this.menu_position + 'px;
                    this.menu_bar.style.backgroundPosition = this.menu_position -8 + 'px';
                    [...select_menu_item.parentElement.children].forEach(
                        sibling => {
                            sibling.classList.remove('tab-current');
                        });
                    select_menu_item.classList.add('tab-current');
                }.bind(this));
            }
        )
    }
}

let menu_tab = new TabBar();
menu_tab.initMenu();
```

```css
:root{
    --primary-color:#0D6FFA;
    --accent-color:#49CE95;
    --danger-color:#EC3582;
    --fore-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    --main-cast-shadow: 0px 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
body{
    background-color:#D9D8D7;
}
.tab-bottom-bar{
    position:absolute;
    display:flex;

    padding: 16px 36px;
    justify-content:space-between;
    width:335px;
    margin:auto;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    height: 32px;

    font-size:26px;
    background-image:radial-gradient(circle at 36px 6px,transparent 36px, #ffffff 37px);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px -1px 6px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)) drop-shadow(0px -2px 12px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12));
    border-bottom-left-radius:30px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:30px;
    transition: cubic-bezier(0.57, 0.23, 0.08, 0.96) .45s;
}

.tab-nav-indicator{
    position:absolute;

    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    bottom: 28px;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;

    background-color: #000000;
    box-shadow: var(--main-cast-shadow);
    border-radius:50%;
    transition: cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.73, 0, 0.59) .3s;
}
.tab-menu-item{
    color:var(--fore-color);
    transition:ease-in-out .5s;

    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-current{
    position:relative;

    color:#ffffff;

    z-index:3;
    transform:translate3d(-2px,-22px,0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-bottom-bar">
            <a href="#" class="tab-menu-item tab-current"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
            <a class="tab-nav-indicator"></a>
            <a href="#" class="tab-menu-item"><i class="fas fa-book-reader"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="tab-menu-item"><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="tab-menu-item"><i class="fas fa-at"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you provided has a syntax error and your post title does not match the error in the text. Make sure the example is working :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called this problem. When you nest functions as you do, you created nested scopes. In those scopes, this reference changes as the nesting goes. If you want to keep the reference you have 2 choices.

1. Use arrow functions
2. Define a variable that points the right this

```
 // this  is different
Array.prototype.forEach.call(parent.children,
      function(select_menu_item){
       // than this
         select_menu_item.addEventListener('click', function(e){
              // and this is different than the other two
```

> Solution 1

```
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(parent.children,
            (select_menu_item) => {
                select_menu_item.addEventListener('click', e=> {
```

> Solution 2

```
let that= this;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(parent.children,
      function(select_menu_item){
        select_menu_item.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                      // use that here.
```

Comment: Solution 2 works halfway, I have my icons which change depending on the click of the mouse but my indicator (black circle) remains fixed and does not move according to the icon select. I have no error message. Maybe it comes from the offset position

Comment: @EzekielNKstars `this.menu_indicator.style.left = this.menu_position + 'px;` there is a type (missing ') on that line. Is that your original code?

Comment: not my code, i try to update it https://codepen.io/vladracoare/pen/RwwMqBL

Comment: try with `that.menu_position = this.offsetLeft - 16;` this refers to selected_mene_item and that refers to class instance

Comment: it looks like it loses offsetLeft of the indicator shot does not move, I can't fix it

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it loses offsetLeft of the indicator shot does not move, I can't fix it.

Error fixed :)

```
class TabBar {
constructor()
{
    this.menu_bar = document.querySelector('.tab-bottom-bar');
    this.menu_item = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-menu-item');
    this.menu_indicator = document.querySelector('.tab-nav-indicator');
    this.menu_current_item = document.querySelector('.tab-current');
    this.menu_position;
}

initMenu()
{
    this.menu_position = this.menu_current_item.offsetLeft -16;
    this.menu_indicator.style.left = this.menu_position + "px";
    this.menu_bar.style.backgroundPosition = this.menu_position - 8 + 'px';
    let that = this;
    this.menu_item.forEach(function(select_menu_item) {
        select_menu_item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            that.menu_position = this.offsetLeft -16;
            that.menu_indicator.style.left = that.menu_position + "px";
            that.menu_bar.style.backgroundPosition = that.menu_position - 8 + 'px';
            [...select_menu_item.parentElement.children].forEach(
                sibling => {
                    sibling.classList.remove('tab-current');
                });
            select_menu_item.classList.add('tab-current');
        });
    })
}
```

}

let menu_tab = new TabBar();
menu_tab.initMenu();