# Cant access variable in Angular in Http Service?

Tags: angular, typescript

Im trying to set my this.lati variable to the latitude in order to use ip in my API Call but I cant reach it in successFunction(), it return null and I take set it :S

Any help?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http'



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class GetApiService {
  lati = "123"

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  apiCallCurrent() {
    return this.http.get('https://api.met.no/weatherapi/nowcast/2.0/complete?lat=57.708870&lon=11.974560');
}

  apiCallForeCast() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction);
    } else {
      alert('It seems like Geolocation, which is required for this 
        page, is not enabled in your browser. Please use a browser 
         which supports it.');
    }
    function successFunction(position: any) {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var long = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log('Your latitude is :' + lat + ' and longitude is ' + long);
      console.log(this.lati)
}


    

    return this.http.get(`https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/complete?lat=${this.lati}&lon=11.974560&altitude=12`);
  }
}
```

Comment: `console.log(this.lati)` in this line `this` is not your component.

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62911287/javascript-typeerror-cant-access-property-offsetleft-this-is-undefined/62911460#62911460) question

Answer (score 1):

Try moving succesFunction outside of apiCallForecast, and remove the "function" keyword out of the definition. Also, you should probably use the pattern below for calling successFunction:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http'    
 
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class GetApiService {
  lati = "123"

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  apiCallCurrent() {
    return this.http.get('https://api.met.no/weatherapi/nowcast/2.0/complete?lat=57.708870&lon=11.974560');
  }

  apiCallForeCast() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo => this.successFunction(geo));
    } else {
      alert('It seems like Geolocation, which is required for this 
        page, is not enabled in your browser. Please use a browser 
         which supports it.');
    }        
  }

  successFunction(position: any) {
      const lat = position.coords.latitude;
      const long = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log('Your latitude is :' + this.lat + ' and longitude is ' + this.long);
      console.log(this.lati)
    

    return this.http.get(`https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/complete?lat=${this.lati}&lon=11.974560&altitude=12`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
lati = "BLABLA";

public async myPrincipalFunc() {
    const context = this;

    doSomething();

    function doSomething() {
        console.log(context.lati);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this you need an alias for the context:

```
 lati = "234";

public  apiCallForeCast() {
  

 successFunction(){
   const myontext = this;      
   // to do
    console.log(myontext.lati);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that you are not passing the data into success function.
You can do it by anonymous functions like this

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo => this.success(geo));
```

Here is working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k3tptn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)